# how to undone the effect of keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyup

what it does is that when the input is entered it change the css and enable the button, but if the input is deleted it's not returning to previous stage i.e., disable and opacity 0.6........

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $('.gbutton').attr('disabled',true);
    $('.gbutton').css( "opacity" ,"0.6" );

    $('#textid').keyup(function(){

        if($(this).val.length !=0){
            $('.gbutton').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.gbutton').css("opacity","1");
        }


    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is method, not a property. Should be:

```
$(this).val().length
```

Also per @BlackSheep comment you should use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: ... and for modifying properties, `.prop()` should be used instead of the `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $('.gbutton').attr('disabled',true);
    $('.gbutton').css( "opacity" ,"0.6" );

    $('#textid').keyup(function(){

        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length) {
            $('.gbutton').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.gbutton').css("opacity","1");
        }
      else
     {
       $('.gbutton').attr('disabled',true);
       $('.gbutton').css( "opacity" ,"0.6" );

     }


    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($(this).val().length !=0){
        $('.gbutton').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.gbutton').css("opacity","1");
    }
```